# Should I run variable selection within MICE for Multiple Imputation?

Tags: r, model-selection, overfitting, multiple-imputation, mice

I have a dataset with around 100 variables, and I plan on getting multiply imputed datasets using the `mice` package in `R`. The literature I have read seems to advocate regressing each variable against all the others (possibly using interactions too) at each stage of the algorithm. I am concerned that this may lead to over-fitting, potentially worsening the imputations made.

Is this a valid concern? If so, how can I attempt to handle this? e.g. are there known ways to run variable selection within the `mice()` function in `R`, or would I have to specify a predictor matrix beforehand based upon my subjective belief about which variables would influence each other (which doesn't seem like a great solution).

Comment: For those interested, it seems this is a potential problem, and there is some advice on selecting predictors given here (pages 23-25):
http://www.stefvanbuuren.nl/publications/MICE%20in%20R%20-%20Draft.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your source you could have a look at [van Buuren (2012, p. 128)](http://bacbuc.hd.free.fr/WebDAV/data/Bouquins/van%20Buuren%20-%20Flexible%20imputation%20of%20missing%20data.pdf.pdf). Here, the author of mice explains some reasons to select a subset of variables in more detail.

I don't know a built in option in mice, which selects variables, but you might want to have a look on automatic variable selection methods, e.g. [elastic nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization) and [lasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) via the `glmnet` package or [random forests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) via the `randomForest` package. You would have to do the selection variable by variable and you would have to specify a predictor matrix in `mice` manually. But with these methods you would not have to select the predictors upon your "subjective belief".

> Is over-fitting a valid concern?

Like you said, most literature suggests to include as many variables as possible. However, I also haven't found any extended discussions about the topic of over-fitting yet (if somebody else knows some good literature, please share).